# ContentPadding in MapBox?

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android, mapbox-android-maps

So Google Maps has `contentPadding` option and set padding for both GoogleMap's UI elements and centering annotations (markers, route) at the specific area and when you set it then you make elements belowe/above other app's UI or status bar/system navigation bar:

[image]

[image]

But I don't know how to implement the same for MapBox Maps:

[image]

[image]

I tried the following MapBox option:

```
Package com.mapbox.maps
Class EdgeInsets
java.lang.Object
com.mapbox.maps.EdgeInsets

public final class EdgeInsets
extends java.lang.Object
implements java.io.Serializable
The distance on each side between rectangles, when one is contained into other. All fields' values are in `platform pixel` units.
```

But it didn't change position of MapBox's UI elements, mb it's only for centering custom annotations

Is it even possible with MapBox on Android?